# cellForRowAtIndexPath not correctly presenting cells, when used with NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nstimer

I have weird situation. I have tableview with photos. I can add new photos in tableview using some button. Before appearing on tableview cell should show progressView for random number of seconds. For this I'm using NSTimer. Everything works fine, except when adding multiple images simultaneously, it is also showing progressView loading in some already loaded cells if I scroll up. I checked my if condition (the only way to start loading) by NSLog, it shows only loading cells indexes. I appreciate your help:)
Here is code for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"photoCell"];

PhotoCell *photoCell = (PhotoCell *)cell;
//if there is active timer
if([self.activeTimerIndexArray containsObject:indexPath]){
    [photoCell.resultImageV setHidden:YES];

    UIProgressView *progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
    progressView.frame = CGRectMake(photoCell.resultImageV.frame.origin.x, photoCell.resultImageV.frame.size.height/2, photoCell.resultImageV.frame.size.width, photoCell.resultImageV.frame.size.height);
    [progressView setTag:11];
        [photoCell.contentView addSubview:progressView];
}
UIImage *img = (UIImage *)[self.resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
photoCell.resultImageV.image = img;
return cell;
```

Here is code for updateTimer method:

```
Timer *timerInfo = timer.userInfo;
NSIndexPath *index = timerInfo.forIndex;
PhotoCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];
if(timerInfo.time >= timerInfo.totalTime)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIProgressView *prg = [cell viewWithTag:11];
        [prg removeFromSuperview];
        [cell.resultImageV setHidden:NO];
    });
    [timer invalidate];
    //no longer active timer
    [self.activeTimerIndexArray removeObject:timerInfo.forIndex];
}
else
{
    timerInfo.time += 0.01;
    float progress = timerInfo.time/timerInfo.totalTime;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIProgressView *prg = [cell viewWithTag:11];
            prg.progress = progress;
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @vadian, I updated my model, created simple class for timers and used timerInfo array as above.

Comment: Basically it's very bad practice to use timers in `cellForRow`. Consider that cells are reused and can be deallocated immediately.

Comment: I removed timer to the button, the same problem

Comment: Maybe, it is associated with threads?

Comment: Remove any active lodingView in - (void)prepareForReuse

Comment: Yes, it did the job, thank you @DeryckLucian:)